# Cannot Archive Array of Values Representing CGPoints

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nskeyedarchiver

I have converted `CGPoint` To `NSValue` and put all the resulting values in q `NSArray` but when I use `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:ArrayName toFile:PointArrayFile];` it gives me error.

So what's the problem?

Comment: What's the error? How about posting some code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what problem you're seeing but in general you're probably better off using `NSStringFromCGPoint` and `CFPointFromString` to store and retrieve the points.